# Why do all magic schools have streaming?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems, class-structure, knowledge

Streaming is the practice of grouping students based on their magical potential, usually at the end of the entrance exam the candidate has to don a talking pointed hat which then announces their respective classes. Supposedly this should encourage competitiveness in gifted classes while improve sportsmanship in borderline cohort who otherwise drop out of school entirely. I like to think streaming isn't promoting elitism but then the latter isn't all that bad except 99% of them would experience Dunning Kruger effect and magic can be very dangerous in the wrong hand, so my question is why must there be streaming for all magic schools?

Comment: Is this a 1-time thing -- a new student is placed in the A, B or C educational track and that's that? Or are they resorted after each final exam? Or are there no cohorts -- a student may be in A-level potions, but C-level talismans and so on, moving individually up or down every few months in each area?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**We go at the speed of the slowest student.**

Classes go at the speed of the weakest student. If you go faster the weaker students get left behind and you "waste" teaching hours by teaching them to cast half a fireball (no fireball) in the time the stronger students need to master the spell. Then when you learn Fire Storm the following month, half of your class is completely lost.

If we stream the classes, then after two months the slow class learns Fireball and the fast class learns Fireball and Fire Storm. Without streaming the fast students learn both spells but the slow students learn only one half of one spell. Everything beyond that is wasted.

That is assuming the slow students just sit quietly the rest of the time and don't *disrupt the class* by asking for help. This will slow the class down further.

> 99% of them would experience Dunning Kruger effect

Dunning-Kruger is when an unskilled or unknowledgable person overestimates their ability. I have no reason to believe streaming encourages Dunning-Kruger.

In any case it is hard to think you are the best, in a school environment, where there is always someone more skilled and knowledgeable than you. They are called the teachers.

Your Dunning-Kruger students are the ones in the top of the class, who are smart enough to make short work of their lessons, but not smart enough to do further independent study.

They tried to learn more spells from the library, once. But it was ten times more work than learning in the classroom. Since they are the next Merlin the problem must of course be with the system. So the next Merlin wastes their energy complaining about how they are the next Merlin and how the school teaching model is corrupt. The school is teaching them the wrong spells on purpose, to prevent them rising up, and make it much harder to learn independently.

> magic can be very dangerous in the wrong hand

The school is aware of this and runs mandatory "Safety and the Arcane" modules so no one forgets it too. Not even the brightest students are allowed to shoot from the hip. Everyone must sit Safety every year. It is pass/fail and it is not streamed.

The module is really boring and good for taking overconfident students down a peg. They cannot *outsmart* the 100 major steps of Cauldron Maintenance. They just have to memorize the steps and then perform a six hour demonstration at the end of the year. The course is pass-fail, which means they get the same mark as a weaker student who passes.

Answer (score 7):

## Because magic is dangerous in the wrong hands.

There are basically three categories of people, and magic.

At the very bottom are people who are pretty bad at magic. They can't manage more complicated spells and they fuck up a lot. These sorts are pretty common and you don't want them to be useless. You teach them very basic magic. In combat classes you teach them how to point and throw big objects, in homemaking classes you teach them how to generate power for magical cleaning spells. You don't teach them anything complicated that's gonna hurt them or others.

They're still useful to society, you need people who work hard. Some of them even get a lot of power, and manage to make good use of their ability to do very simple things a lot.

In the middle are the average people. You teach these people a variety of complicated charms so they can manage to live normal lives. They can learn a bunch of cleaning charms and more advanced combat spells that let them handle things much more flexibly than others. They can get good jobs in government and corporations with a good grade. You don't give them the really complicated stuff.

At the top are the elite students. You don't teach them the really dangerous stuff like demon summoning, that's for apprentices, but you teach them much more complicated charms that can go very wrong including ones that rely on tight emotional control or which can kill people with less potential. Those who do really well can get top jobs in corporations and governments, and get a chance to apprentice to wizards to learn the really dangerous spells.

Answer (score 0):

Only because you said there must. Where else is that written?

Never you mind no magic; streaming is the practice of grouping students by potential.

Never you mind no talking pointed hat, either.

Magic or mundane, where is it written that streaming should encourage competitiveness in gifted classes, or improve sportsmanship anywhere?